# A Weird error in Azure data flow when I tried to run a innerjoin

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-synapse-analytics

Refer the image below ,I have the filters and conditional splits like this :
[image]

When I datapreview the **RightFilter2** (Rows are coming) ,**Filtered** (Rows are coming) which are going through the **inner join** where i have given **col1from left ==col1 from right**, its showing up the wierd error. If there are no matching rows ,it should have given me 0 rows /No output data .but it throws an error in datapreview as well as when i run the dataflow through pipeline. [image]

[image]

Comment: try to work on the intermediate resultset generated --- more steps but tends to be the right path to get there where you need to be ...

Comment: The error occurs when using inequality join condition and the error message indicates the same, but you are not using an inequality condition. Can you give additional information about what you are doing or trying to do? Also, try selecting a broadcast stream in the optimize tab as shown in this image https://i.imgur.com/pQa9PPy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As shown in your image, you are using `==` condition on the inner join which should work as expected. However, the error message indicates usage of inequality condition for join which is unclear.
- The following is an example where I am using joins but with inequality condition:

[image]

- When I validate it, I get the following error indicating a message similar to yours:

[image]

- To overcome this, navigate to optimize tab in the join transformation. Select one of the streams as broadcast.

[image]

- After this, you would get the result of the transformation that you are looking for. The following is an image for reference where I got the result of the join after overcoming the error.

[image]

Comment: but am not using non equality. Why Auto broadcast is failing.

Comment: The error is indeed strange given the configurations used. But check if the above solution worked.

Comment: The transformations used might be causing the issue as the dataflow validation is not giving any error in your case. But the error message is shown while using data preview

Comment: there are just simple filters in thos conditional splits and filter like col1=="" && not(isNull(col2)) . Nothimg else.

Comment: i have used fixed Broadcast,its wotkimg But Why Auto Broadcast is not working . athats all i want to know.